# was 'constructed by' or 'constructed from' or 'built by' or 'built from'

Tags: word-choice

This data set ***was constructed from*** 50 participants ....

Which of the four expressions in the title in correct?

Comment: Did the participants make the data set? Was it made by them? Or was the data set made by a researcher, and did the researcher collect data from the participants?   All four are "correct" grammar.  But probably none express the truth.  The data set was probably constructed from data that was collected from fifty participants.

Comment: The situation I want to express is 'the researcher collect data from the participants'.

Comment: Using either verb sounds as though the participants physically built something, or their bodies were piled up to build it! As James says, you need to express that it used _data from_ the participants.

Comment: *This data set was **collected** from 50 **subjects.***

Answer (score 2):

None of the above. As the comments say, whilst the grammar is correct, the meaning almost certainly isn't what you intended. You should try something like

> The input (data?) from 50 subjects was used to construct / build the data set.

Either construct or build is OK in this context, but I don't like the use of the word "data" twice in one sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> The situation I want to express is 'the researcher collect data from the participants'

Bing!

That's right (or nearly right) In this sentence you have the right subject "The researcher"  and the right verb "collect".  This is a much better sentence than "The data set was ..."

> The researcher collected data from fifty participants.  (or fifty subjects)

Now we know who did what we can talk about

> The data set is ....

We can use "The" data set, because there is context to know *which* data set.  (It is the data set with data from the fifty)